# json_encode returns &quot;

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I am trying to build a chart with Chart.js using laravel. The json_encode function returns the string with & quot; instead of " that Chart.js cannot recognize. Tried the htmlspecialchars_decode() with no luck.  Is there any other workaround ? Please help.

This is the laravel code

```
  labels: {{  htmlspecialchars_decode(json_encode($sm_names)) }},
                datasets: [{
                data: {{  str_replace('"','',json_encode($sm_totals))}},
```

and this is how it is rendered in javascript:

```
labels: [&quot;John&quot;,&quot;Mercy &quot;,&quot;Gary&quot;],
                datasets: [{
                data: [425000,470000,10000],
```

Comment: where is your json and json call..?

Comment: @AjayMakwana Edited the code.

Comment: @KAndy , Yes its the same topic.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you use blade, try `{!! json_encode($sm_names) !!}`

Comment: I am using blade. Tried this and its returning the same.

Comment: That worked !! Thanks...

Comment: Many thanks for this! Been banging my head against the keyboard for the past hour trying to figure why it was outputting &quot;.

Comment: wow ! awesome ans. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!, I have been looking everywhere!, this solved my problem